# How to serve both frontend & backend as multi-container app on Azure App Service through Nginx

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, nginx, azure-web-app-service

### Goal

I'd like to have Nginx in front of both frontend & backend container to proxy different request to different container.

So that when user make request to my Azure App Service default domain, they'll see the React app, and when the request is append with `/api` route, the request is proxy to Express Server.

- App stack (3 containers are stored on ACR)

  - Proxy server: Nginx (container, exposed on port 80 as default serving container)
  - Frontend: React (container, exposed on port 3000 in Dockerfile)
  - Backend: ExpressJS (container, exposed on port 8000 in Dockerfile)

[image]

### Docker Compose Config on Azure

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    image: myid.azurecr.io/nginx:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  react:
    image: myid.azurecr.io/react:latest
  express:
    image: myid.azurecr.io/express:latest
```

### Nginx Config

```yaml
upstream frontend {
    server react:3000;
}

upstream backend {
    server express:8000;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    }
}
```

### Question

Currently Nginx can only proxy to my frontend container, when I make request to `https://my-domain/api` Nginx response with 404 error. How can I config my Nginx so that backend server is been accessed properly?

Comment: Are you sure that nginx does not reach the node.js app and the 404 comes from there? If nginx had trouble contacting your node app there would be normaly a 500 error instead of 400.

Comment: @Marc you're right!! I just forgot to add URL rewrite to my backend location setting, I'll add that to this post, appreciate!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Marc 's reminder that 404 error means that my server is serving yet the url is undefined, I found that I forgot to add URL rewrite to my backend location setting, so after the update the Nginx config should look like this,

```yaml
upstream frontend {
    server react:3000;
}

upstream backend {
    server express:8000;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    }

    location /api/ {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break; # Add this rewrite option and it all works!
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```